# Ubuntu Touch - Phone battery issue

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery

I have the bq Aquaris E5 which I have been usibg now for a month or so.

Recently I have noticed that the battery around the 5 - 2% left runs out really fast. The other night I got the warning that there was 5% left. I got out the chair, walked 5 steps, got the charger out my bag and plugged it in. By the time I had done this say 1 minute, the phone battery had gone from 5% to 2%, then died. Surly the 5% to dead battery life should last longer than a minute. The 100% to 10% lasts just under 2 days.

Has anyone any experience of this or know anything to fix?batter

Comment: I've had even worse problems with the E4.5 - the battery goes from more than 50% to 0 in a few minutes... Even sent the phone to BQ for repairs but it still does it so I just gave up... no matter whether the phone is flashed with Ubuntu Touch or Android.

Comment: Oh my gosh that is bad, makes me think that mine is good. The thing that makes me wonder is that I have always only charged my phone, once the battery was fully flay.

Comment: Similar experience here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/769842

Comment: I have found that now I have my ”Adjust automatcally” in my Brightness settings, this is helping to save the battery a bit more. Not much more though.